# How can I skip a file I already downloaded & deleted, and resume the torrent?

Tags: utorrent

Whilst downloading a torrent, I decided I didn't want a particular file any more. I paused uTorrent, right-clicked the file in the list, and chose *Don't Download*. Then I deleted the file.

When I resume the torrent though, I see this:

[image]

How can I resume the torrent? I want to resume the torrent from where it was up to, and I don't want to re-download the file I didn't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the torrent, and choose *Force Re-Check* (note: not *Force Start*):

[image]

Then just click [image] and the torrent will resume!

Answer (score -1):

I believe this how it goes.  And it must be done in this order or you'll have problems.

First, stop the download.  Second, delete the actual file from the folder.  Third, right-click on the file in utorrent and select "Don't Download".  Fourth, just hit Start.  Done!

Comment: Doing this would probably result in the error in the question. Regardless, the question is how to get past that error (a Force Re-Check is needed).